# Selecting a DOM element that doesn't have any selectors whatsoever

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

I desire to select a DOM element that doesn't have any selectors whatsoever (and it's not my site so I can't add these myself).

Let's assume I cannot target it by textContent or offsetWidth because many other HTML objects (elements) in the webpage has the same textContent and/or offsetWidth, so it's not a good method in this case, by principle.

### My question:

I would assume each DOM element has a "machine-identifier" of some sort, that I could utilize to select the object with document.querySelector.

It might be selected by a unique number (index) in an array (if we look at the DOM tree as an array).

Is there indeed any machine identifier or index I could utilize to select the element with document.querySelector?

I tried to search for such but basically I didn't find any. Maybe the terminology I used was wrong.

I don't look for a jQuery or CSS solution, but rather only vanilla JS.

Comment: can you post an example of the html of that element?

Comment: Did you try using xPath ?

Comment: Kaddath, no, because I ask it on any HTML element whatsoever so I don't have an example for a specific element I would like to target.

Comment: caramaba, no, I didn't know the term till this moment.

Comment: if you don't give us any criteria on what you want to target, or what it looks like, this is the generic answer: use the appropriate selector..

Comment: I don't agree, I asked if any element whatsoever has a unique machine identifier or else, by an index in the DOM array.

Comment: There is no such thing as "an element that has no selectors whatsoever" - **every** element can be reached with at least one selector. Every single one. Jeremy Thille's answer demonstrates this.

Comment: Yes, I had a mistake there - I meant to selector in the sense of ID or Class. I now know that CSS-PATH is the most basic selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your element in Chrome, and select `inspect`.

Then, in the inspector, in the HTML code, right-click it again and choose `copy selector` (or `copy Xpath`).

For instance, if I want to select the words "**My question:**" from your question, it gives me :

`#question > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.postcell > div > div.post-text > h2`

This is the unique absolute CSS selector for this element.

Comment: Using a similar button, near Xpath, gave me the selector ("selection path") I so desired. Thank you for showing the right direction.